# List does not exist error

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

> List does not exist.
>
> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user

This issues happens when I click on items to view. How can this be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Is it a custom list and any workflow associated? This is mostly likely a permission issue, verify the permission on the list.